# Grant access to a node (during the node creation) to anonymous user

Tags: nodes, drupal-8, email-notifications

I'm looking for a solution on how to grant access to an anonymous user during a node creation.

**Scenario:**

- A registered user creates a node with comments as one would normally
  do, but there would be another field. This would be an email address
  to which a message would be sent to an anonymous user. The email
  would contain a link to access and edit the node by the anonymous
  user (who, from then on, would become a registered one).
- Also, once a comment is posted on the node, **ONLY** the new node editor
  is notified via email to approve or delete the comment.
- The new node editor is able to manage comments **ONLY** on their node.
  Changing comment number in the URL bar, while in edit mode, would
  bring the new editor to, say, "Page not found" or "Access denied".
- The initial node creator **CANNOT** manage the new user.

I'm using **Drupal 8** and **[Comment Notify](https://www.drupal.org/project/comment_notify)** module.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[Claim on Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/claim_on_registration) module seems to be a great fit for that.

The only thing to figure out is the third point in the scenario above. The new editor not being able to modify a comment ID in URL bar. Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Thanks